# Can't get out of the do{}while(); loop (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

For some odd reason I just can't get out of that loop that asks to enter the answers, any help would be awesome:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int TEST=20;
    char crctAnswrs[TEST]={'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
                           'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
                           'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
                           'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};
    char stdntAnswer[TEST];

    for(int index=0; index<TEST; index++){
        do{
            cout<<"Please enter the answer for question #"<<(index+1)<<": ";
            cin.ignore();
            char input;
            cin.get(input);
            stdntAnswer[index]=input;
            if(stdntAnswer[index]!='A' && stdntAnswer[index]!='B' &&
               stdntAnswer[index]!='C' && stdntAnswer[index]!='D'){
                cout<<"Please enter A, B, C, or D as an answer."<<endl;
            }
        }while(stdntAnswer[index]!='A' && stdntAnswer[index]!='B' &&
               stdntAnswer[index]!='C' && stdntAnswer[index]!='D');
    }
}
```

Edit: changed the conditions, i entered them wrong for this example. Every condition now has !=   The problem is the same, it can't break out of the loop.  I would think that if one of the conditions is false, then the entire condition set is false, thus causing it to break out of the loop... however, it still loops and the validation message still gets displayed if I enter  A, B, C, or D.... is it something with cin.get()?  I don't want to use getline() because that's not what the book is asking to do.

Comment: paddy already found the problem, it was ignore(), thanks for the none-constructive comment.

Comment: Love the people that instead of answering the question will complain about other people's answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Noobacode: It's called peer review, and it's _one of this community's greatest strengths_. Otherwise how do you know that the answer you are getting is correct?

Comment: I understand that, but at the same time, I truly spent a very long time trying to find the problem, and simply looked at the wrong part of the code due to being new.  If a new person gets downvoted simply for asking a question he truly can't find a solution to... how is that of any help?  Mind you, I didn't ask for solution, I asked for help.  I got the help and I'm thankful, but received 3 downvotes? Wow, shame on me for being inexperienced.

Comment: @Noobacode: Stack Overflow is a Q&A. It is for questions, and answers. That is, _problems_ and _solutions_. The reason you got 3 downvotes is exactly what you said: you weren't looking for anything concrete. You wanted a chat about how to go about solving your issue. That's what discussion forums and chatrooms are for, which is not Stack Overflow. In short, "asking for help" is not a magic bullet for on-topicness on SO.

Comment: An answer != solution.  You're an angry person.  Look at your comments in this post -- half of them are pointless.  You're the one chatting, off-topic 100% of the time.  That's all I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call `cin.ignore()` prior to reading a character.

That will cause it to ignore the *next* input character (because the `cin` stream does not have EOF if it's just sitting there waiting for input).  So you will always be getting an 'enter' instead of the letter.

Do the ignore *after* you read the character, or better still, use `getline` to read a string.

You could have worked this out by displaying the character (or its value) that was read.  Standard debugging practice: "why is this thing that should work not working?"

Comment: Yeah, we'll getline would be a great option, but i was trying to figure out with the cin.get()...  let me see if that cin.ignore() is the issue, be right back...

Comment: YES SIR, that is the problem.  Thank you very much.  I've been at it for almost an hour, sweating my butt off. :)

Comment: The problem with using `get` is you don't know how many characters the user will enter.  If they enter a space or something else, how many characters should you ignore?  You could do the `get` and then discard characters until you see a newline, but that's just about the same as `getline` anyway.

Comment: Yep, I truly agree.  The only reason I wanted to use cin.get(char) is to experiment with every possible way of doing business.  I myself use getline() for a lot of stuff, but I want to learn as much as I can about the other elements.  Thank for your help once again.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing `std::cin.ignore()` prior to reading, I suggest doing something like `std::cin >> input` or `std::getline(std::cin,input)` while `input` is an `std::string`. If you stick with `std::cin >> input` then you should probably call `std::cin.ignore(20,'\n');` to discard the newline.

Comment: Yeah, so if it's equal to one of them, it should break out of the loop?

Comment: Had that logic too, didn't work.  I've tried almost every possible condition on the truth table.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's something to do with the pesky cin.get()

Comment: Why don't you do `std::cin >> input` then call something like `std::cin.ignore(20,'\n')` to ignore the left over '\n'.

Comment: -1: Isn't your suggested code precisely equivalent to the existing code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It isn't. OP edited the post, it had this exact mistake before. Rapptz just corrected it, but then the question got edited.

Comment: @Rapptz Or `std::getline(std::cin, input)`, but in this case, input has to be a `std::string`.

Comment: @JesseEmond: Okay but now. OP has `(A != B && C != D)`, and Rapptz suggests `(!(A == B || C == D))`. The two are equivalent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes they are. So the answer becomes kind of "invalid". That's what Jesse said...

Comment: @leemes: Alright then. In a twist of irony, Jesse has added to his comment since I saw it last. :)

Comment: "if u love paddy so much y dont u just marry him??"

Comment: Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: And I'm not sure what _your_ problem is, since you didn't ever write a question.

Comment: Reading ability used to be common thing.